# scalaj-http Multiple Parameters on Get

Tags: scala

I have an RESTful API call that looks like the following:

```
http://xxxxx:9000/api/parameter/value?ecosystem_name=streaming_pipeline&ecosystem_key_name=kafka_brokers
```

Which works fine when I use it through postman or Swagger. When I run scalaj-http on it:

```
val result = Http("http://xxxxxx:9000/parameter/value").params(Map(("ecosystem_name", "streaming_pipeline"), ("ecosystem_key_name", "kafka_brokers"))).asString
```

I get a not found response. This has worked with other calls when I use just a single parameter:

```
val result = Http("http://xxxxxx:9000/api/schemas/name").param("schema_name", schemaName).asString
```

Why is it when I try and use multiple parameters it seems to be failing? I have tried using .param(...).param(...) instead of the .params with no luck either.

Edit based on:

```
scala> val result = Http("http://xxxxx:9000/parameter/value").params(Map("ecosystem_name" -> "streaming_pipeline", "ecosystem_key_name" -> "kafka_brokers")).asString
result: scalaj.http.HttpResponse[String] = HttpResponse(,404,Map(Content-Length -> Vector(0), Date -> Vector(Tue, 26 Jul 2016 17:53:49 GMT), Server -> Vector(Apache-Coyote/1.1), Status -> Vector(HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)))
```

Comment: I just realized you used a different url for the call with one parameter. Why?

Comment: You nailed it I messed up the /api not sure why I skipped over it, guess a long day of coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are not initializing properly the `Map[String,String]` parameter for the `params` function. The correct way to initialize a Map is:

```
val myMap = Map(key -> value, key2 -> value2)
```

So your get request would looks like this:

```
val result = Http("http://xxxxxx:9000/parameter/value").params(Map("ecosystem_name"-> "streaming_pipeline", "ecosystem_key_name"-> "kafka_brokers")).asString
```